# Why does changing a UITextView's frame origin completely disfigure my entire frame size?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, resize, uitextview, frame

I have a UITextview with a small UIViewController on top of it, whose view is a UITextView (It's red in the screenshots).The small red textView is the subView of the bigger textView under it.

Heres what it looks like. The small textView is red and is in the shape small square (let's say 50 x 50). It is purposely cut of the edge of the screen. That's how it's positioned.

[image]

This is in portrait. When the device is rotated to landscape, I'd like the small textView to move to the left so it's no longer on top of the bigger textView, but it's still a subview. So I make a new CGRect that's the same size as the small textView's frame, and then change the x coordinate of the origin. Then reassign the small textViews frame to the altered one. Here's how:

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        CGRect smallFrame = self.smallTextView.view.frame;
        smallFrame.origin.x -=20.0;
        self.smallTextView.view.frame = smallFrame;
    }
}
```

Heres the result:

[image]

Obviously this is incorrect. I don't even touch the textView's frame size, but those attributes are changed! What's stranger is that if I NSLog the size dimensions, they are the same as they were before the rotation, 50 x 50.

A few observations:

1. This only happens when the small red textView is a textView. I could replace that view with a UIImageView and this problem does no occur.
2. I'm fairly certain this is happening because it's a subview of another UITextView. Why? How? No clue.
3. I'm starting to think the problem lies in how the big superview UITextView is rotating, and somehow the subview small red textView is being effected some way. Even though "Autoresize Subviews" in interface builder is not checked for either textViews. The large superview textView is constrained to a specific width and height in IB with constraints. So the size doesn't really change there.

I'd really appreciate some help with this. I've been looking at it for a few days and just can't pinpoint a cause or solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this a while ago. Assigning the textView's `center` property instead of its `frame` solves the problem.

```
CGPoint center = self.smallTextView.view.center;
center.x -=20.0;
self.smallTextView.center = center;
```

Even still, assigning the textView's `frame` with a different `origin` still causes the bug, even in iOS 7. But assigning the center works just fine.